# ¿Como manipular array en code igniter sin el nombre de una tabla?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo obtengo de la siguiente manera desde el modelo:

```
$result = $this->db->get();
return $result->result();
```

Quisiera saber como manipular ese array por numeros de filas que se obtiene, ya que estoy intentando hacer un ABM dinamico, trayendo datos de diferentes tablas.

Comment: No se lo que es un ABM ni conozco codeigniter, pero lo que te devuelve `$result->result()` es un array de objectos. Lo puedes recorrer mediante un bucle (foreach, for, while, etc) o bien llamarlo con esta sintaxis supongo: `$result->result()[x]` donde **x** representa el número de fila (empezando por 0).. por ejemplo: `echo $result->result()[0]->nacionalidad;` debería devolverte **Argentino**.

Comment: @masterguru ABM (alta,baja,modificacion). Si pero la idea es no poner "nacionalidad", ya que aveces va a ser una consulta a tabla nacionalidad y otras a tabla "provincia". No se si me logro explicar bien.

Comment: Entonces, tendria que recorrer la consulta solamente por $result->result()[0].

Comment: y no por un atributo de una tabla.

Comment: No se si te refieres a esto: `echo (array_values((array) $array[0]))[0];
echo (array_values((array) $array[0]))[1];` donde nos comemos sus propiedades pasandolo a array y luego sacando sus valores solamente.

Comment: @masterguru pruebo y te aviso! Muchas gracias!

Comment: @masterguru Si me re sirvio !! Estaría mejor si se pudiera conocer el tamaño del ultimo **[0]**

Comment: Osea, viste que en tu segundo echo pusiste [1] al final, bueno estaria bueno saber si en algun caso puede existir un [2]

Comment: Le puse un 1 porque en tu array de ejemplo tan solo habia dos propiedades, pero si quieres saber el total de propiedades que tiene puedes hacer un `echo count((array) $array[0])` y para saber el total de índices tan solo debes restarle 1 (porque los indices empiezan por 0): `echo (count((array) $array[0])-1)`